# Access of configuration variable in Cloud Functions Firebase CLI local emulator failed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am using Firebase Functions. I set a environment variable by command:

```
firebase functions:config:set my.token="abcde"
```

I verified it by command:

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

which returns me:

```
{
  "my": {
    "token": "abcde"
  }
}
```

in my **index.js** , I try to get the set token by:

```
const tok = functions.config().my.token
```

I would like to test my functions locally instructed by [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator), so I run command:

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

But it gives me error:

```
Error from emulator. FirebaseError: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
```

Why I can't access the token I set in environment variable of Firebase?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was a bug in the Firebase CLI that was fixed in version 3.17.4.  Please update your firebase-tools module:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Also, don't forget to follow the instructions in the documentation and copy your configs to a local file before running the emulator:

```
cd functions
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

Comment: Did you remember to create `.runtimeconfig.json` as suggested in the documentation you pointed to?

Comment: Thanks! That works! BTW, do you know do I need to run the command to copy to local file every time I update the configuration settings?

Comment: If you want to change your config, yes, you have to recreate the file with those changes for local emulation.

Comment: Perhaps this answer is outdated, but [the instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) do not mention a `.runtimeconfig.json` file.

Comment: It's difficult to search up this `.runtimeconfig.json` stuff, even when you know what you are looking for. Eventually found this answer again.